# How do I pass a mysql number type data from php to Javascript to arrive as a string type?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, database

I am trying to retrieve data from the mysql database and pass it to a javascript array. This data would be a date that looks like this: 2021-09-16.
This data arrives at js as a number type so it does the calculation:
2021-09-16 = 1995
A query is made between script tags in a php file.

```
<script>
    const bookedArray = [
        <?php 
        
         $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
         $dates = mysqli_query($connection,'SELECT * FROM `booking_dates`');
         foreach($dates as $date){
             echo "$date[day] ,"; 
         }

        ?>
    ];
</script>
```

The elements arrive in the array, but not correctly due to the "-" operator.

How can i solve it?

Comment: So what does the table schema look like and what data is held in the `day` column

Comment: Your approach is quite cumbersome and unsophisticated, IMHO. You should rather stick your data into an array in PHP, and then use `json_encode` to create a representation that JS can "read", instead of trying to assemble the JS code manually.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the output, 2021-09-16 should be a string, so at least add `'` in your code like that:

```
echo "'" . $date['day'] . "',";
```

(replace the inside of your foreach loop)

Comment: I tried something similar like that but probably wrong.
Your solution works, thanks for the help.